# unable to register spark session on GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, geospatial, geospark

I have been trying to register spark with GeoSpark. I have installed apache sedona 3.1.3 version in python 3.7. Spark session has created using

```
#Import required libraries
import os

import folium
import geopandas as gpd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from geospark.register import GeoSparkRegistrator
from geospark.utils import GeoSparkKryoRegistrator, KryoSerializer
from geospark.register import upload_jars

    #Generate spark session
upload_jars()
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
        master("local[*]").\
        appName("TestApp").\
        config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName).\
        config("spark.kryo.registrator", GeoSparkKryoRegistrator.getName) .\
        getOrCreate()
```

spark session:

SparkSession -

```
in-memory

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
    v3.1.3
Master
    local[*]
AppName
    TestApp
```

When I tried to register this spark session with geospark using command:

```
GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)
```

, I'm getting error py4javaerror like this:

```
    {
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <module>
----> 1 GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(spark)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geospark/register/geo_registrator.py:24, in GeoSparkRegistrator.registerAll(cls, spark)
     15 @classmethod
     16 def registerAll(cls, spark: SparkSession) -> bool:
     17     """
     18     This is the core of whole package, It uses py4j to run wrapper which takes existing SparkSession
     19     and register all User Defined Functions by GeoSpark developers, for this SparkSession.
   (...)
     22     :return: bool, True if registration was correct.
     23     """
---> 24     spark.sql("SELECT 1 as geom").count()
     25     PackageImporter.import_jvm_lib(spark._jvm)
     26     cls.register(spark)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:680, in DataFrame.count(self)
    670 def count(self):
    671     """Returns the number of rows in this :class:`DataFrame`.
    672 
    673     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    678     2
    679     """
--> 680     return int(self._jdf.count())

File ~/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:111, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    109 def deco(*a, **kw):
    110     try:
--> 111         return f(*a, **kw)
    112     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/ox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:173)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.borrow(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$PoolWrapper.borrow(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serializeStream(KryoSerializer.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1509)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5(DAGScheduler.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1213)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2432)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2421)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datasyslab.geospark.serde.GeoSparkKryoRegistrator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$7(KryoSerializer.scala:168)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:168)
    ... 26 more

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2252)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2251)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1443)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5(DAGScheduler.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1213)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2432)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2421)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2261)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:390)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1(Dataset.scala:3019)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$count$1$adapted(Dataset.scala:3018)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3700)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3698)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:3018)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to register classes with Kryo
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.$anonfun$newKryo$5(KryoSerializer.scala:173)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.withContextClassLoader(Utils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer.newKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$$anon$1.create(KryoSerializer.scala:102)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.borrow(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer$PoolWrapper.borrow(KryoSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.borrowKryo(KryoSerializer.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.<init>(KryoSerializer.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serializeStream(KryoSerializer.scala:422)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1509)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5(DAGScheduler.scala:1274)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$submitStage$5$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1213)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2440)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2432)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2421)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datasyslab.geospark.serde.GeoSparkKryoRegistrator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
}
```

Please help. I need to run this for geospatial analysis. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and resolved it by adding the following JAR files to the spark session creation:

```
.config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded- 
3.0_2.12:1.4.0,' 'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.4.0-28.2')
```

You can see the complete direction here:
https://sedona.apache.org/1.3.1-incubating/setup/install-python/